# Error: use of deleted function when I try to use a reference

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I started learning c ++ and I ran into this compilation problem. When I change size of `al2` I need to change size in `al.get(0)`.

Full compilation error message:

```
arraylist.cpp: In instantiation of 'void jpparl::ArrayList<T>::add(T) [with T = jpparl::ArrayList<int>]':
arraylist.cpp:90:15:   required from here
arraylist.cpp:46:33: error: use of deleted function 'jpparl::ArrayList<int>& jpparl::ArrayList<int>::operator=(const j
pparl::ArrayList<int>&)'
                 array[usedSize] = elem;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
arraylist.cpp:5:30: note: 'jpparl::ArrayList<int>& jpparl::ArrayList<int>::operator=(const jpparl::ArrayList<int>&)' i
s implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
     template <class T> class ArrayList {
                              ^~~~~~~~~
arraylist.cpp:5:30: error: non-static reference member 'long int& jpparl::ArrayList<int>::usedSize', can't use default
 assignment operator
In file included from arraylist.cpp:2:0:
jppsys.cpp: In instantiation of 'static void jppsys::JPPSystem::arraycopy(T*, long int, long int, T*, long int) [with
T = jpparl::ArrayList<int>]':
jppsys.cpp:10:22:   required from 'static void jppsys::JPPSystem::expand(T**, long int, long int) [with T = jpparl::Ar
rayList<int>]'
arraylist.cpp:42:46:   required from 'void jpparl::ArrayList<T>::add(T) [with T = jpparl::ArrayList<int>]'
arraylist.cpp:90:15:   required from here
jppsys.cpp:5:78: error: use of deleted function 'jpparl::ArrayList<int>& jpparl::ArrayList<int>::operator=(const jppar
l::ArrayList<int>&)'
             for (long i = 0; i < srcEnd - srcStart; i++) dest[destStart + i] = src[srcStart + i];
                                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
```

And my source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "jppsys.cpp"

namespace jpparl {
    template <class T> class ArrayList {
        long l = 0;
        long &usedSize = l;

        private:
            T *array;
            int step;
            long totalSize;

        public:
            ArrayList(long step) {
                this->step = step;
                totalSize = step;
                array = new T[step];
            }

            ArrayList() {
                this->step = 8;
                totalSize = step;
                array = new T[step];
            }

            void add(T elem, long index) {
                if (usedSize == totalSize) totalSize += step;

                T *tmp = new T[totalSize];
                jppsys::JPPSystem::arraycopy(array, 0, index, tmp, 0);
                jppsys::JPPSystem::arraycopy(array, index, usedSize, tmp, index + 1);
                delete[] array;
                tmp[index] = elem;
                array = tmp;

                usedSize++;
            }

            void add(T elem) {
                if (usedSize == totalSize) {
                    jppsys::JPPSystem::expand(&array, usedSize, usedSize + step);
                    totalSize += step;
                }
std::cout << usedSize << " add\n";
                array[usedSize] = elem;
                usedSize++;
            }

            void remove(long index) {
                if (usedSize == totalSize - step) totalSize -= step;

                T *tmp = new T[totalSize];
                jppsys::JPPSystem::arraycopy(array, 0, index, tmp, 0);
                jppsys::JPPSystem::arraycopy(array, index + 1, usedSize, tmp, index);
                delete[] array;
                *array = *tmp;
                usedSize--;
            }

            void remove() {
                if (usedSize == totalSize - step) {
                    jppsys::JPPSystem::expand(&array, usedSize - step, usedSize - step);
                    totalSize -= step;
                }

                usedSize--;
            }

            T get(long index) {
                return array[index];
            }

            long size() {
                return usedSize;
            }

            long getTotalSize() {
                return totalSize;
            }
    };

}

using namespace jpparl;
using namespace std;
int main() {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<int>> al;
    ArrayList<int> al2;
    al.add(al2);
    al2.add(256);
    cout << al2.size() << " " << al.get(0).size() << "\n";
}
```

I will be grateful for help

Comment: The error message clearly explains that since your ArrayList class has usedSize member that is reference to long it can not be assigned with = because the references can not be reseated.

Comment: A class with a reference member gets a deleted assignment operator. In approximately 100% of the cases, a reference member is not something that you need. Why is `usedSize` a reference? (It's even a reference to `l`, which you never use.)

Comment: @molbdnilo objects with reference members can certainly be copy constructed but what OP code is doing is copy assignment.

Comment: btw in school i made fun of a teacher because he tried to convince me that `l` is not a good variable name, it took me some time to understand what he meant, but now I am completely on his side ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <class T> 
class ArrayList {
        long l = 0;
        long &usedSize = l;
```

Having a reference in your class implicitly deletes your `operator=`, you need to rewrite it, also I'm not really sure why you would want a private reference to your class variable? If you remove the reference and just use the `l` variable it should work.

Also, `#include "jppsys.cpp"`

don't include `.cpp` files.

Comment: Well, how do I make the size of `al.get(0)` change when changing the size of `al2`? If I do not use reference, the `usedSize` will not change in `al.get(0)`, only in `al2`

Comment: @congard why would you want the size of one list to be changed when another list is modified? Regardless, you can use a pointer instead of a reference. Pointers are assignable.

Comment: `al.get(0)` and `al2` are different variables, when you use `al.add(al2)`, you are making a copy of `al2`, so `al.get(0)` and `al2` are 2 different objects now.